# Practical log viewing methods in linux?

Tags: linux, logging, tail

I'm developing my c++ project in linux and use syslog and stdout for logging. Although I know *tail -f, tail -f | grep hoge* command, sometimes I miss some important message.

So I want to ask you about practical ways for checking log in linux. I usually working on terminal via ssh. Are there any good way for checking log? I mean that some useful commands or tools for log in linux.

Comment: SO is for questions about computer programming, not about using computers in general.

Comment: i usually use `less`

Comment: "sometimes I miss some important message". But how is that related to the tool being used? For someone to suggest another way, one would need to know why you  "miss some important message" with the methods you are already using.